# How to find all documents with specific string in field?(Elasticsearch)

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document with fields:

```
"provider": "AppStore",
"device_model": "iPad3,6[graphicsDeviceName: PowerVR SGX 554]",
"days_in_game": 34,
```

And I need to get all documents with `iPad` string in `device_model`!

Is it possible?

Comment: It does not work? `{
    "match" : {
        "device_model" : "iPad"
    }
}`

Comment: @ruhungry I've tried this '{
    "query": {"match": {
       "device_model": "ipad"
    }}
} 
and it gives me nothing((

Comment: Try this and paste the output: `http://<HOST>:<PORT>/<YOUR_INDEX_NAME>/_mappings?pretty`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two types of search queries in Elasticsearch ie. term queries and match queries. The match first analyzes the query string, then looks for documents containing the words in the query and returns result depending upon how closely it matches.
What the term query does is basically a yes or no query and will return only the documents that have an exact match. 
I think for your case a term query is better fit. And since field does not contain the exact word iPad but something like iPad3 you should use a prefix, wildcard or possibly a regexp query depending upon what your document actually contain(take a look at [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/term-level-queries.html))

You could use the following query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "device_model": "iPad" 
    }
}
```